# element.text() after element is rendered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

so I have two custom filters on the same element and each has shared scope .
I want the second directive to read the element text , but the thing is , the element text is generated by the first directive ..

```
app.directive('newEl', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element) {

        console.log("link element : ", element.text())

        }, controller: function($scope, $element) { 

        console.log("controller text ",$element.text())           
        }
      }     
});
```

Comment: First, there is optional require. But anyway, getting element text is so weird... why u need this? What exactly does label-data? Can it be replaced by filter? seems like you mixing view and model...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov , actually I am making the text editable on click in this directive , so I am adding onclick behaviour that is drawing a text with save and cancel ,, all I am left to need is the actual text of the element so I put the initial value to be edited inside this text .

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vb4N6ae6beHX0EwFXPnU?p=preview this is how you pass parameters to directive

Comment: @PetrAveryanov i dont want to have isolated scopes in my page , having so many especialy that im using ngrepeat will slow the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `$timeout` it will make sure that timeout expression is run after the digest cycle and data is bound to DOM. Since you have `ng-repeat` on the same element you can make sure that the element is rendered only after you have data bound to it.

```
  $timeout(function(){
     console.log("link element : ", element.text(), $scope.item)
  }, 0, false); //set false if you dont want to trigger a digest
```

But it is weird to do that though, you could instead use an isolated scoped directive and bind the value of `item` there via 2-way binding.

In your directive settings:

```
 {
   scope:{item:'='}
 },
```

and access it as `$scope.item` in your directive. You could also use `controllerAs` and `bindToController` and get `item` as a property of controller instance with this. Avoid accessing `$element` in your controller and you can use this technique. Isolated scope helps you create a self contained component with no tight coupling with the consumer.

Or as simple as that set it as attribute to `edit-text` i.e

```
<td ... edit-text="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</td>
```

and in your directive do:

```
var item = $scope.$eval(attrs.editText);
```

Also since your directive does not create a scope, you could as well access it as `$scope.item` but not so recommended as it is not explicit enough and there are some assumptions about the parent.

```js
angular.module('app', []).run(function($timeout, $rootScope) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  }, 2000);

}).directive('editText', function($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log($scope.$eval(attrs.editText), $scope.item);
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log("link element : ", element.text())
      });

    },
    controller: function($scope) {


    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div edit-text="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first of all you can try to use angular.element.ready. The second one is postLink.

Comment: that did not work , did not even get in the function of it